# auto selection of a radio button on selection of radio button from another set

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is this set of radio buttons

```
<div class="wrapper"> <strong> Number of images:</strong>
<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" />100
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="200" />200
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="300" />300
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="400" />400
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="500" />500
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="600" />600
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1000" checked="checked"
    />1000
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1200" />1200
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1500" />1500
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="1600" />1600
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="other" />other
</div>
</div>
```

And there is this set of radio buttons

```
<div class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Number of additional pages:</strong>

<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="0" />0
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="1" />1
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="2" />2
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="3" />3
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="4" checked="checked"
    />4
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="5" />5
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="6" />6
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="7" />7
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="8" />8
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="9" />9
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="10" />10
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumberPages" value="other" />other
</div>
</div>
```

how can I make it in jquery that on selection of "other" from rdNumber automatically selects "other" radio button of "rdNumberPages"?
here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k4Y4z/

Comment: Arun's answer is correct, but to make things easier, faster and more reliable, you should name every input field differently. That would make them easier to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this

```
var rdNumberPages = $('input:radio[name="rdNumberPages"]');
var rdNumbers= $('input:radio[name="rdNumber"]');
rdNumbers.change(function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is(':checked')){
        if($target.is('[value="other"]')){
            rdNumberPages.not('[value="other"]').prop('disabled', true);
            rdNumberPages.filter('[value="other"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            rdNumberPages.not('[value="other"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k4Y4z/6/)

Comment: thanks a lot arun.. can it happen that on selection of other from rdnumber selects the other from rdnumberpages (which you already done) and also it disables other radio buttons of rdnumberpages and enables them when other of rdnumber is deselected or 100, 200, etc is selected fro rdnumber?

Comment: thumbs up fr u and all maximum points I can give u, I gave.. thanx a lot.. :)

Comment: in order to run it on webpage I have to make it $(document).ready(function() { ????

Comment: @aks yes, you need to, or the short cut `$(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 1):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/k4Y4z/5/

```
$('#other1').click(function() {
   if($('#other1').is(':checked')) { $('#other2').attr('checked', 'checked'); }
});
```

Comment: remember put the "id" for "other" radio button, see fiddle =]

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

```
$('input:radio[value="other"]').change(function () {
  $.each($('[value="other"]'), function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```